# How do you perform an action over each file using make?

Tags: makefile

Let's say I have this:

```
FILES = c:/file.c c:/another_file.c
```

and I want to do something to each of the files. For example, I'd like to apply `cygpath` to each of the files. How can I do that? I would like a solution based on an external program, instead of a built-in `make` function please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is unclear. If you mean you want to get at the `cygpath`'d path names, use something like:

```
CYG_FILES := $(shell cygpath $(FILES))
```

Comment: Remark: It's important to use `:=` over `=` here because otherwise it will execute the `$(shell)` command every time `$(CYG_FILES)` is expanded, which is great for killing performance.